# perl: symbol lookup error: /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0: undefined symbol: SSLeay

Tags: perl, docker, cpan, unixodbc, cpanm

I'm building a perl application inside of a docker container based on *`perl:5.22 which is based on debian:stretch`*
I have used cpan to install a bunch of perl related packages.

I get the following error when running an *`odbc_test.pl script`*. 
I haven't ran into that error before, the issue seems related to *`libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev`* which I found googling around but I'm not sure whether that's what's causing my issues.

I get this error below:

*`perl: symbol lookup error: /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0:  undefined symbol: SSLeay`*

P.S I'm completly new to Perl, my job is to only package this app inside of a docker container so the inner workings of perl are somewhat obscure/blackbox to me.

Has anyone ran into that error before?

Comment: Can you share some sample code that we can run to reproduce this problem? Also, can you try changing the base image to `debian:wheezy`.

Comment: My base image is actually *`perl:5.22`* which when you drill down further ends up on *`debian:stretch`* so I can't change that since *`perl:5.22`* is a requirement for our app; but I could look for a different perl tag which would end up on *`debian:wheezy`* and experiment with that. Just curious, why did you suggest *`debian:wheezy`* over *`debian:stretch`*? Is that more stable? I'll see how share my dockerfile in a way that'll make sense

Comment: Actually I just double checked and there's no wheezy base image for perl as of today. But i'm still wondering if there's a benefit to using a wheezy base over the stretch base. Maybe I could build my own custom image if it's worth the effort